# C++ Exception thrown: read access violation (fopen/fread struct)

Tags: c++, struct, fopen, fread

Here is my structure:

```
struct Account {
string accID;
string name;
float balance;
string currency;
int status; 
};
```

Function:

```
Account layFileTaiKhoan(string id) {
FILE * openfile;
Account getAcc;
string mypath = "Account\\" + id + ".dat";
openfile = fopen(mypath.c_str(), "r");

fread(&getAcc, sizeof TaiKhoan, 1, openfile);

fclose(openfile);

return getAcc;
}
```

But I got this error: "Exception thrown: read access violation" when using my function to get struct saved in .dat file.

Please help me to solve this error and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Whats `TaiKhoan`?

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. Pick the one you compile as and edit the question accordingly (including tags)!

Comment: @PeteBecker: I didn't know C has a type `string` and supports the addition operator on string literals.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot `fread` a `std::string` (or an object containing a `std::string`), since the `std::string` object only contains pointers to the actual string of characters (except for short strings with some library implementations.) Reading a previously-written pointer is meaningless and using the pointer is Undefined Behaviour.